# MVC Issue model item passed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am getting this error when running my project:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType12`1[System.Int32]]',
>   but this dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var IA =
        _context.IA
     .Select (x => new  { x.GUId }).Distinct()
     .ToList();

    return View(IA.ToList());
}
```

Comment: For future reference, the model-view-controller tag is only intended for questions about the _pattern_. Use the asp.net-mvc tag when referencing the ASP.NET implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing an anonymous type on your View with this code:

```
var IAMark =
      _context.IAMarksheetResults
     .Select (x => new  { x.GUId }).Distinct()  //This converts your list to anonymous type
     .ToList();
```

If you want distinct and still passing the expected model, you can do this:

```
var IAMark =
      _context.IAMarksheetResults
     .GroupBy(x => x.GUId ).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault())
     .ToList();
```

Comment: It gave me error and suggested to use firstordefault , with the use of firstordeafult it works. Thanks